# Invoking a context menu, from within the rowContext callback, with the target row data

Tags: contextmenu, tabulator

[Edited for clarity (I hope!)]

I've been using Tabulator for a while now (just about to look at moving to 4.0!) so think I have a reasonable grasp of the basics, and am a great fan!

In this particular case, I am using a table to hold a waitlist.  The user (internal) may need to trigger one of several actions, on any given row and targeting either that row or the data in the row, as required.  Given this scenario I am looking for a right-click context-menu scenario.

I am able to capture the right-click event through the rowContext callback, and extract the data (row.getData() etc.) for immediate action i.e. console.log(), etc.

**Tabulator Config:**

```
            waitListName = "waitlist" + bayID;
            console.log("Creating waitlist:", waitListName);

            let column_array = [];
            column_array.push({id: 1, title:"Index", field:"index", align:"center", headerSort: false, width:40});
            column_array.push({id: 2, title:"Name", field:"name", align:"center", headerSort: false, width:100});
            column_array.push({id: 3, title:"Qty", field:"throwers", align:"center", headerSort: false, bottomCalc: "sum" ,width:40});
            column_array.push({id: 4, title:"Listed", field:"waitlisted", align:"center", headerSort: false, width:60});
            column_array.push({id: 5, title:"Waited", field:"waittime", align:"center", headerSort: false, width:60});
            column_array.push({id: 5, title:"ETA", field:"eta", align:"center", headerSort: false, width:60});

           // Calculate width of tabulator table
            let table_width = 0;
            column_array.forEach ( row => {
                table_width += row.width;
            })

            // Define tabulator table config                
            let tabulator_config = {
                layout: "fitData",
                responsiveLayout:true,
                columns: column_array,
                movableRows: true,
                rowMoved: rowMovedHandler,
                rowContext: waitlistTableContextMenu
            }

            // Creat new tabulator table div
            let $newdiv = $("<div/>")
                .attr("id", waitListName)
                .addClass("waitlist")
                .css({
                        width: table_width + "px",
                    })
                .appendTo('#waitlist_container');

            // create tabulator in new table div
            $newdiv.tabulator(tabulator_config)
```

**rowContext Handler**

```
    // define context menu for a waitlist table
    function waitlistTableContextMenu(e,row) {
        let data = row.getData();
        console.log("Right click in waitlist!");
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log(row);
        //console.log(data);

        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the browsers default context menu form appearing.
    }
```

I am also able to create and attach a basic context-menu to the individual table rows by anchoring it to the **.tabulator-row** class.

*Note: I am using the jQuery-contextMenu library - https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html - but I've messed with a few historically, they mostly work in a similar fashion*

```
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.tabulator-row',
        build: function($triggerElement, e) {
            console.log($triggerElement);
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    var m = "clicked: " + key;
                    console.log(m); 
                    console.log(options);
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                   copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                        return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                    }}
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

All of the above works successfully and I get the context menu as expected when I right click on a row.

[image]

Where I am failing is in being able to reference the tabulator row/row data from within the context-menu callback once an option is selected.

Maybe I'm just being dense? :)

I am using the dynamic menu build option (funnily enough, called "build") which captures the triggering element and allows the menu structure to be built at call time, however when referencing that element I'm obviously getting the underlying table element/structure of a Tabulator rowDiv

```
jQuery.fn.init [div.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable.tabulator-row-even]
0: div.tabulator-row.tabulator-selectable.tabulator-row-even.context-menu-active
accessKey: ""
align: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 2}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: role, 2: style, class: class, role: role, style: style, length: 3}
autocapitalize: ""
baseURI: "http://tetris.local/walkins2.html"
childElementCount: 6
childNodes: NodeList(6) [div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell]
children: HTMLCollection(6) [div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell, div.tabulator-cell]
classList: DOMTokenList(4) ["tabulator-row", "tabulator-selectable", "tabulator-row-even", "context-menu-active", value: "tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-even context-menu-active"]
className: "tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-even context-menu-active"
clientHeight: 23
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 360
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: div.tabulator-cell
firstElementChild: div.tabulator-cell
hidden: false
id: ""
innerText: "2Aurelia211:09 am31:02 pm"
.
.
.
```

And while I can see some of the data elements (innerText, etc.) I don't see an elegant way to extract.

Alternatively I could manually build something super-basic on the fly within the Tabulator rowContext call-back, but I hate re-inventing the wheel (don't we all?) so I'm hoping I'm missing something really basic here....

Any thoughts gratefully appreciated!

Shaun

Comment: Please post a copy of your table constructor so we can give you some pointers

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

As of version 4.7 there is now built in menu functionality in Tabulator. You can use the ***rowContextMenu*** option to configure it:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowContextMenu:[
        {
            label:"Delete Row",
            action:function(e, row){
                row.delete();
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Checkout the [Menu Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu#header-menu) for full details on how to use these features

#### Original Answer

Firstly i would recommend using your context pluggin inside the ***rowFormatter*** or ***cellFormatter*** and passing the element to the plugin rather than the selector, that way all your callbacks have the ***row*** component in scope. also as Tabulator uses a virtual DOM trying to bind to rows inside the table will only get the currently visible rows not the ones currently scrolled off the screen

If that is not possible then you can pass the Jquery DOM element of that row, which tou should be able to access in your context plugin into the ***getRow*** function to return the row component for that row.

Which in this case i believe is in the ***this*** context of the callback function for the context plugin:

```
callback: function(key, options) {
     row = $("#example-table").tabulator("getRow", $(this));
},
```

Although if you are on version 3.5.x there may be an issue with the lookup based on elements in some cases so you may need to move to version 4.0 for that.

On the whole i would recomend using the ***rowFormatter*** as it will make your life much easier.

Comment: I've taken a stab at this in a pen @ [link](https://codepen.io/shaunhurley/pen/pOMvvV ) and it felt like a little progress, however I haven't got it right.  I'm able to assign the context menu on an element by element basis as you suggested, and while I still have to provide some kind of selector in the context-menu definition, using just 'div' seems to work, in that I get a unique instance of the context-menu per row.  Unfortunately the this reference is returning a [div.tabulator-cell.context-menu-active] and failing.  Would this be the lookup issue you mentioned above?  Thanks!

Comment: Your code pen example is great, in that example the row variable passed into the rowWithContextMenu is the Row Component that you need!

Comment: Ahh, the light dawns!  How did I miss that!  Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: One last query, to make my day complete :) I am currently using a jQuery .parent() chain (invoking .parent() three times then calling .attr("id")) to identify the tabulator instance that I am in (assume there could be up to 4) - is there an easier way? Note: updated the pen to illustrate what I mean...

Comment: what do you need to do with the id? if you are just trying to call a function on the parent table you can call the ***getTable*** function on the row component. (if you using version 4.0) if you are on version 3.x then it would be easier to call row.getElement().closest(".tabulator") to get the tabulator holding element

Comment: If you think this answer has helped you out, would you mind marking it as the correct answer so it can help others in future? Cheers :)